# Adding random integers to outer cells of a grid in python

Tags: python, arrays, grid

I have a grid for a game set out as below:

```
grid = [(0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        (0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        (0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        (0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        (0,0,0,0,0,0,0)]
```

I need to iterate through the outer cells of the grid and randomly turn them into either "1" or "0".

Is there a way of doing this quickly whilst maintaining the ability to change the size of the grid and still perform the same thing?

thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is a grid for a game, you probably should rather use a list of lists rather than a list of tuples, as tuples are immutable. Personnaly, I probably would define my own class for representing the board, however.

Comment: Following the comment above, 'immutable' means that the Tuple (indicated by the parentheses) cannot be changed. To change outer cells, you need something mutable (like a list, as suggested).

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should use lists instead of tuples, tuples are immutable and cannot be changed.

**Create grid as list with lists**

```
grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This should do the trick, though one of the python-gurus may have an even easier solution.

**First Edition**

```
#go through all the lines
for index, line in enumerate(grid):
    #is the line the first or the last one
    if index == 0 or index == len(grid)-1:
        #randomize all entries
        for i in range(0, len(line)):
            line[i] = randint(0, 1)
    #the line is one in the middle
    else:
        #randomize the first and the last
        line[0] = randint(0, 1)
        line[-1] = randint(0, 1)
```

After toying around some more I could replace the nested for with a list comprehension to make the code more readable

**Second Edition**

```
for index, line in enumerate(grid):
    if index == 0 or index == len(grid)-1:
        grid[index] = [randint(0, 1)for x in line]
    else:
        line[0] = randint(0, 1)
        line[-1] = randint(0, 1)
```

If someone points out an easier/more readable way to do the if I would be glad.

Answer (score 1):

If you represent your grid as a list of lists (rather than a list of tupples), then it's a matter of iterating over the outer cells and setting:

```
grid[x][y] = random.randint(0, 1)
```

... considering that by "randomly turn them" you mean "change them with 50% probability".

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy , and you don't need to iterate at all .

```
import numpy as np
grid = np.array([(0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        (0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        (0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        (0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        (0,0,0,0,0,0,0)])
grid[[0,-1]] = np.random.randint(2,size=(2,grid.shape[1])) 
grid[:,[0,-1]] = np.random.randint(2,size=(grid.shape[0],2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrays through numpy module to improve performances as follow:

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint

def random_grid():
    while True:  
        grid = np.array([randint(0, 1) for _ in range(35)]).reshape(5,7)
        yield grid

gen_grids = random_grid()
print gen_grids.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Jan's answer

```
from random import randint
grid = [[0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0]]

for x, j in enumerate(grid):
    for y, i in enumerate(j):
        grid[x][y] = randint(0,1)
print(grid)
```

This is a simple solution independent of whatever is the size, but if performance is critical, then go for numpy.